# CSS Flexbox - Responsive issue on mobile view

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Please check this web page on [codepen](https://codepen.io/joyal-developer/pen/WNRqYWm)

(images are attached below)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        * {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            border: 0;
        }
        
        html {
            height: 100%;
        }
        
        body {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            font-size: 15px;
            height: 100%;
        }
        
        .flex-container {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            max-width: 1100px;
            padding: 40px;
        }
        
        .flex-item {
            padding: 20px;
            height: 500px;
            width: 300px;
            background-color: aqua;
        }
        
        @media only screen and (max-width: 920px) {
            .flex-container {
                flex-direction: column;
                align-items: flex-start;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="flex-container">
        <div class="flex-item" style="background-color: royalblue;">
        </div>
        <div class="flex-item" style="background-color: bisque;">
        </div>
        <div class="flex-item" style="background-color: blueviolet;">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am a frontend beginner

The page looks good on desktop view (3 boxes horizontally aligned on center). On mobile view I want to align the boxes vertically. but top box (blue box) is partially hidden.

How can I fix it ?

[desktop view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dywve.png)

[Mobile view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVp77.png)

Comment: just remove height:100%; css rule for body.

Comment: @Asturion the reason I set body height:100% is that I want to set the flex-container vertically center.